# Not able to commit my changes from Github Desktop

Tags: android, git, github, github-desktop

Here is the error message I got whenever I hit commit button on Github Desktop

```
Running ktlint over these files:
AnkiDroid/src/main/java/com/ichi2/anki/AnkiActivity.kt
AnkiDroid/src/main/java/com/ichi2/anki/NavigationDrawerActivity.kt
api/src/main/java/com/ichi2/anki/FlashCardsContract.kt
api/src/main/java/com/ichi2/anki/api/AddContentApi.kt
api/src/main/java/com/ichi2/anki/api/NoteInfo.kt
./gradlew: line 249: /cygdrive/c/Users/Avanish/AppData/Local/Android/jdk-21_windows-x64_bin/jdk-21.0.2/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I tried direct commit from Android studio Terminal and it worked ,but failed from github desktop.

Comment: This seems unrelated to GitHub Desktop?

Comment: Check the `JAVA_HOME` ENV variable. It may point to a non-existent JDK installation, see the path in the last line.